# No mapping for GET secure/home - spring mvc

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I can't figure out what is wrong with my setup in my app. The app loads fine with no errors and the login page works. It is once the user logs in and tries to access the home endpoint that it crashes and i am met with a

> No mapping for GET /app-name/secure/home

the jsp file is located in WEB-INF/jsp/secure/home/view.jsp

Can anyone spot what is wrong with my setup? i am struggling to understand what is going wrong.

Here is my **home controller**

```
@SecureController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    public HomeController() {
        super();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("userInformation")
    public SystemUserDetailsDto getUserDetails() {
        String username = UserInfoHolder.getUserInfo().getUsername();
        return username;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String handle() {
        return "home/view";
    }
}
```

this is my **defaultSecureController implementation**

```
@SecureController
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class DefaultSecureController {

    private String servletContext = "secure/";

    @RequestMapping
    public String handle(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf(servletContext) + servletContext.length());
    }
}
```

this is the **secure-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.web.mvc">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="com.app.web.mvc.SecureController" />
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <bean class="com.app.application.core.userinfo.UserInfoInterceptor" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <bean class="com.app.web.interceptor.SessionTimeoutInterceptor">
                <!-- Preempt the default session timeout by 5 seconds to allow interceptor to work -->
                <property name="sessionMaxInactiveIntervalPreempt" value="5" />
                <property name="timeoutMapping" value="/app/public/login?expired=true" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
    
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="2" />
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/secure/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="exceptionHandler" class="com.app.web.mvc.ExceptionHandler">
        <property name="exceptionView" value="displayError" />
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

and this is the servlet configuration in my **web.xml**

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>secure</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/secure-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>secure</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Debug code and tell us which instruction is failing?  Try removing : @RequestMapping("/*")

Comment: can't debug anything cause it doesnt hit the endpoint - tried removing that but didnt do anything

Comment: See following : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-404-error

Comment: managed to get it working now - will upload answer when i get time